# how to club multiple cases with OR in case statement in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have a case statement in plsql ,
and the thing is for more than one case i am calling same procedure , so don't want to call the same function again and again and want to club the cases together which call same procedure.

```
LOOP                                                                         
FETCH cu_my_cur INTO lr_my_rec;                                                 
EXIT WHEN cu_my_cur%NOTFOUND;

CASE lr_my_rec.method_name
    WHEN 'ProductName' THEN
         -- population record with product name , product version and product type
         p_required_det(pn_product_reference => pr_mi_exits.policy_reference
                       ,pv_product_name      => pr_out_rec.product_name
                       ,pn_product_version   => pr_out_rec.product_version
                       ,pv_product_type      => pr_out_rec.product_type);

    WHEN 'ProductVersion' THEN
         -- population record with product name , product version and product type
         p_required_det(pn_product_reference => pr_mi_exits.policy_reference
                       ,pv_product_name      => pr_out_rec.product_name
                       ,pn_product_version   => pr_out_rec.product_version
                       ,pv_product_type      => pr_out_rec.product_type);
    WHEN 'ProductType' THEN 
         -- population record with product name , product version and product type
         p_required_det(pn_product_reference => pr_mi_exits.policy_reference
                       ,pv_product_name      => pr_out_rec.product_name
                       ,pn_product_version   => pr_out_rec.product_version
                       ,pv_product_type      => pr_out_rec.product_type);
    ELSE              
        NULL;
END CASE;
```

END LOOP;

I want something like this ,

```
CASE lr_my_rec.method_name 


WHEN 'ProductName' OR 'ProductVersion' OR 'ProductType' THEN 
  -- population record with product name , product version and product type
         p_required_det(pn_product_reference => pr_mi_exits.policy_reference
                       ,pv_product_name      => pr_out_rec.product_name
                       ,pn_product_version   => pr_out_rec.product_version
                       ,pv_product_type      => pr_out_rec.product_type);
ELSE 
 NULL;
END CASE;
```

But when trying getting error .

Expression is of wrong type.

can you guys please help me to get it done. 
note : I have to use switch only.
cant use IF ELSE things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Replace your `case` like below

```
CASE  WHEN  lr_my_rec.method_name in ('ProductName','ProductVersion','ProductType') THEN
         -- population record with product name , product version and product type
         p_required_det(pn_product_reference => pr_mi_exits.policy_reference
                       ,pv_product_name      => pr_out_rec.product_name
                       ,pn_product_version   => pr_out_rec.product_version
                       ,pv_product_type      => pr_out_rec.product_type);

      WHEN `Other condition` THEN
          ----DO for other cases
      ELSE              
        NULL;
END CASE;
```

EDIT:

From [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html). You have two Syntax for `CASE`

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

Or:

```
CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
    [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

> For the first syntax, **case_value** is an expression. This value is compared to the when_value expression in each WHEN clause until one of them is equal
>
> For the second syntax, each WHEN clause **search_condition** expression is evaluated until one is true, at which point its corresponding THEN clause statement_list executes.

Here we want second form since we are using Search Condition. So if you want to do this. You have to change the `Case` Structure.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. there are 34 cases ,   and out of which only 3 need to be clubbed . do i really need to change the structure of the case. as it would require type  case when lr_my_rec.method_name  30 times instead of just one time as i am using it now.

Comment: Updated.No need to type `case` 30 times.You can do the other cases like shown in code.

Comment: WHEN   other condition is nothing but   
WHEN   lr_my_rec.method_name = 'Something'  30 times. 

are you suggesting to do this.

Comment: I think i'm not getting you. Are you saying that you are having `lr_my_rec.method_name = 'A`,`lr_my_rec.method_name = 'B`,...30 entries? In that case if each method_name is calling different procedures (or doing different operation) then yes, you need to write 30 `WHEN` clauses

Comment: yes , it is like that, and each method_name is calling different procedure expect 3 are calling same procedure and 2 are calling same procedure.

Answer (score 4):

```
declare 
  V_TEST varchar2(10) := 'a';
  V_TEST2 varchar2(10) := 'a';
begin 
  case 
    when v_test in ('a','b','c')then 
      null;
    when V_TEST2 in ('a','b','c')then 
      null;
  else
    null;
  end case;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please refer to the structure in the first example , i have to stick to that structure and there are 34 cases , in your example the structure is changed of case .

Comment: do you mean to say , i need to write  
WHEN lr_my_rec.method_name  in ('productName , ProductReference , 'ProductType') THEN 

well i tried this way , but getting error given the basic structure where the case starts for other cases.

Comment: In plsql exists two type of case statement. "Selector case" and "Search case".

Answer (score 0):

Made changes like below

```
    CASE 
            WHEN lr_my_rec.method_name= 'ProductName' or lr_my_rec.method_name='ProductVersion'or lr_my_rec.method_name='ProductType' 
            THEN
                 -- population record with product name , product version and product type
                 p_required_det(pn_product_reference => pr_mi_exits.policy_reference
                               ,pv_product_name      => pr_out_rec.product_name
                               ,pn_product_version   => pr_out_rec.product_version
                               ,pv_product_type      => pr_out_rec.product_type);

            ELSE              
                NULL;
        END CASE;
```

or you can specify condition like below

```
case
when lr_my_rec.method_name in('ProductName','ProductVersion','ProductType')
then
procedure
else 
null
end
```

Comment: getting error when trying above.
Type mismatch found at lr_my_rec.method_name between case operand and when operand.  PLS 00615

Comment: check it now i have updated. if you get error again let me know:)